# Making a div that covers the entire page

Tags: html, css

I would like to make a div that covers the entire page.  I put a css style with height:100% but this covers only the viewable area.  I want it to also cover the area when I scroll down.

Comment: Here is a great article on how to do just that...

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/get-document-height-cross-browser/

Comment: Check my solution below. Unless I misunderstood your question, the other solutions will only tell you the viewport (window) dimensions, and not the document dimensions...

Comment: CSS solutions will not work for this problem, you will need a little javascript.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Use `position:fixed` this way your div will remain over the whole viewable area continuously ..

give your div a class `overlay` and create the following rule in your CSS

```
.overlay{
    opacity:0.8;
    background-color:#ccc;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

Demo: http://www.jsfiddle.net/TtL7R/1/

Comment: I'm not sure the opacity is required.

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 no its not required. It was added to **show** that the overlay worked while scrolling.

Comment: oh man, couple of days trying to figure this one out!!! thank you very much

Comment: This works very well!

Though not sure how to center elements inside that div now.

Answer (score 7):

Following `css` will do the required job.

```
.overlay {
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Sometimes We want to cover page body with an overlay until all resources of web page are not downloaded completely. And they we fade out this overlay to show the complete content of our web page. Following example is a little modification of above answers, In this example we show an overlay covering full body of page with css3 animation:

For more animations, visit [Here](https://www.pexels.com/blog/css-only-loaders/)

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.overlay').delay(1000).fadeOut(800);
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.loading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
.loading-bar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  animation: loading 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.loading-bar:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #3498db;
  animation-delay: 0;
}
.loading-bar:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #c0392b;
  animation-delay: 0.09s;
}
.loading-bar:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #f1c40f;
  animation-delay: .18s;
}
.loading-bar:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #27ae60;
  animation-delay: .27s;
}

@keyframes loading {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(1, 2.2);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="loading">
    <div class="loading-bar"></div>
    <div class="loading-bar"></div>
    <div class="loading-bar"></div>
    <div class="loading-bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
#page { min-height: 100% }
```

Comment: This is perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 <style type="text/css">
 html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%; 
 } 
 #test { 
    position:absolute; 
    display:block;
    background:#ccc; 
    height:100%; 
    width:100%;
 }
 </style>
```

Comment: this will not work .. `position:absolute` with 100% width and height will still only fit the viewport. if you scroll, it will scroll up and the rest of the page will be without the overlay ..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an opaque background color for the overlay, you can hide the background with a fixed-position div and then show the overlay content on an absolute-position div. The page scroll height will be the larger of the regular page content or the overlay foreground content.

```
    <div style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; background-color:black; z-index:999;">
        <!-- This overlay background hides the regular page content. -->
    </div>

    <div style="position:absolute; z-index:1000; color:white;">
         Overlay foreground content here.
    </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure what you're doing with this div, but you can style the  element as well.