# DIV enlarge to window size on click

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

How to enlarge a div to full screen on click with new content or layout of that div with the help of jquery. Actually i am making a div that is small in a webpage with some text or images written over that div and when i click on that div it go large to window size with more details about the content on the smalle div .

Comment: What have you done so far? Do you want it as a dialog box  i supose?

Comment: no i want it as a new fresh page...

Comment: Why don't you head over to oDesk and hire someone... This is the second question of yours that I have read that basically asks for someone to provide you with code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you already have the means to enlarge the DIV so it [covers your document](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3250861/402022), and now you want it to go **fullscreen**. If that is the case check the [html5 full screen API](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-full-screen-api/). Please note this is currently a [working draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/fullscreen/) so you need to check [compatibility of the browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen) and use the prefixes accordingly.

As long as we are talking about **fullscreen**, then you are in good luck, because there is already a JQuery plugin for that: http://johndyer.name/native-fullscreen-javascript-api-plus-jquery-plugin/ [[Demo](http://johndyer.name/lab/fullscreenapi/)]

Using the plugin this is the relevant code:

```
window.fullScreenApi.requestFullScreen(fsElement);
```

Comment: i want to make it like a windows 8 UI...CLICK ON THE DIV AND MAKE IT LARGE TO WINDOW SIZE(FULL SCREEN) WITH NEW DETAILS N LAYOUT ON THAT FRESH PAGE.

Comment: @AnilPanwar are you sure what you want isn't to navigate to another page? I have already posted how to go fullscreen.

Comment: http://codecanyon.net/item/melonhtml5-metro-ui/full_screen_preview/2986068   i want this type of effect when i click on any div..plz see the link

Comment: Anil - that site is incredibly complex. The use of hashtag addressing suggests a framework like BackboneJS. If you want the effect they have - why don't you ask to buy it off them?

Comment: That requires much more work, for instance you will need the HTML5 History API (http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) to get the navigation to work without reloading the page, also the content is being loaded dynamically which mean some ajax. They also seem to change the styles with media queries (http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Fluid_Design). And that is only the DIVs, you do realise they actually sell this code, right?

Comment: @ANIEGF (sorry, failed to address you in the previous comment).