# opening fresh page on clicking a div

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, dom

Can someone help me to make an effect like on this website - clicking on div results in opening a fresh page.
http://codecanyon.net/item/melonhtml5-metro-ui/full_screen_preview/2986068

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290098/div-enlarge-to-window-size-on-click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: The creators of the effect you want require payment to get their source. That means that I'm not going to help you build an exact duplicate, but I am going to show you how you might be able to do so.

Those animation effects are done by the power of CSS with perheps a little help of HTML 5.
Take a look at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp) to learn how animations in CSS actually work.

You can view a CSS few examples at:
http://daneden.me/animate/
To custom build your animation, you can go here:
http://daneden.me/animate/build/

Look at `flipInY`. You might be able to edit the source to stop it sooner so that it looks just like the effect you want.

You can also use JS to do a few Metro stylish things. Click [here](http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs) to view how.