# Jquery animate.({opacity} not running at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

So in my code I am trying to animate an opacity of a div, when that didn't work, I selected the `img` with chrome, but still, animation doesn't run, I went over the code but maybe i'm missing something.

**The HTML simplified:**

```
<div class="searchWrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 popsImage">
            <img src="img/airplane3.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://www.somesite.com/searchbox"></script>
</div>
```

**The script:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log('starting anim');
        $(".body > div.searchWrapper > div.row > div > img").animate({
            opacity: 0.9
        }, 5000, function() {
            console.log('Animation complete.');
        });
    </script>
```

**and this is the css:**

```
body > div.searchWrapper > div.row > div > img{
    opacity:0;
}
```

So the console does print 'starting anim', but the animation doesn't reach the callback so it doesn't print completion in console.

Can someone spot the issue, would a previous script running could be the culprit?

Comment: put a number as a string? it's in an object.

Answer (score 1):

There is simple typo in your selector a  misplaced `.` before `body`, so change `.body` to `body`. Also put code inside [document ready handler](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) to wait for the page to load.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('starting anim');
  $("body > div.searchWrapper > div.row > div > img").animate({
  //-^------------ remove .
    opacity: 0.9
  }, 5000, function() {
    console.log('Animation complete.');
  });
});
```

```css
body > div.searchWrapper > div.row > div > img {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="searchWrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 popsImage">
      <img src="img/airplane3.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://www.somesite.com/searchbox"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: correc, i removed the "." class selector from body, it still doesn't work.

Comment: it's a pre-loader -it's supposed to run before the document is ready

Answer (score 1):

Instead of jQuery animate, you could add a css class to the image on load, and use css for the animation:

JS

```
$('element').addClass('animate-opacity');
```

CSS

```
.animate-opacity {
    transition: opacity 5s;
    opacity: .9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`body` is html tag but you are using it as class in your code. Remove `.` before it in jQuery code and your animation will work.

```js
console.log('starting anim');
$("body > div.searchWrapper > div.row > div > img").animate({
   opacity: 0.9
}, 5000, function() {
    console.log('Animation complete.');
});
```

```css
body > div.searchWrapper > div.row > div > img{
    opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="searchWrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 popsImage">
            <img src="img/airplane3.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://www.somesite.com/searchbox"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: correc, i removed the "." class selector from body, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @erezT wrap your code inside `$(function() { ... });` it should work.

Comment: I did it like this:
  <script type="text/javascript">
   console.log('starting anim');
   function init()
   {$(".searchWrapper div > img").addClass('animate-opacity', function(){
                console.log('Animation complete.');
            });}
  </script>

Is this correct?

Comment: No, its not correct. If you wants to implement a pre loader then my answer on this question might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250790/making-a-div-that-covers-the-entire-page/37252058#37252058