# Child component doesn't cover whole page

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I want to make a background overlay within a child component. But even if I put the `position` on `absolute` it does not cover the whole page.

This is what I do in the css of my child component:

```
#background-overlay{
  position: absolute !important;
  display: block !important;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding:0;
  margin:0;

  top:0;
  left:0;

  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vw;
}
```

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rjiujw

Comment: if you want the whole page you could use `position: fixed` instead of absolute

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making a div that covers the entire page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250790/making-a-div-that-covers-the-entire-page)

Comment: No sorry both suggestions don't work for me. (see stackblitz example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height and width are switched, they should be:

```
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
```

Comment: Ah yes, this works for my example but unfortunately not in my actual environment. Apparently I wasn't able to simulate it exactly.

Comment: I have editted the stackblitz example to show how it is actually like. Now that I found the difference I think that `ng-content` is causing this problem.

Comment: That problem doesn't exist when I use `position: fixed` but it doesn't work in my code unfortunately.. I give up I can't simulate it on stack I have to keep trying to figure it out myself.

Comment: The problem only exists in mobile view in the ionic framework I think something else interferes with it so I have no choice but to accept this answer now since I can't simulate my problem. Maybe it will help someone else.

Comment: If the overlay has a parent with ```position:relative```, then the overlay coordinates start at the parent. ```<div style="position:relative;height: 100px;top:15px; left:15px">
            <div style="position: absolute; left:0; top:0; width: 50px; height:50px;background-color: red;">
        </div>
```   the inside div 0,0 is at parent div 15,15 on the screen.